# Slope Aspect Curvature algorithm giving error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, saga, slope

I am trying to execute the slope aspect curvature algorithm in QGIS using a stand-alone script. When I run this code, I am getting a 'problem executing algorithm' error, which occurs when trying to run this slope aspect curvature algorithm.

I included my code for creating the clipped DEM and for running the slope aspect curvature algorithm.

[image]

```
processing.runandload('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', 
                       raster_layer,    #INPUT <ParameterRaster>
                       mask_layer,      #MASK <ParameterVector>
                       "none",          #NO_DATA <ParameterString>
                       False,           #ALPHA_BAND <ParameterBoolean>
                       True,            #CROP_TO_CUTLINE <ParameterBoolean>
                       True,            #KEEP_RESOLUTION <ParameterBoolean>
                       5,               #RTYPE <ParameterSelection>
                       4,               #COMPRESS <ParameterSelection>
                       75,              #JPEGCOMPRESSION <ParameterNumber>
                       6,               #ZLEVEL <ParameterNumber>
                       1,               #PREDICTOR <ParameterNumber>
                       False,           #TILED <ParameterBoolean>
                       0,               #BIGTIFF <ParameterSelection>
                       False,           #TFW <ParameterBoolean>
                       "",              #EXTRA <ParameterString>
                       "C:/Users/Rachel/Desktop/clippedDEM.tif")     #OUTPUT <OutputRaster>
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please post code as text instead of images in order to make it possible to search for it and copy it.

Comment: You need to post your code, as in my previous example (fortunately, I had in this case a template), instead of image.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is probably due to second parameter in 'saga:slopeaspectcurvature' method: "Clipped (mask)". It's not a valid path to layer (by the way, you put as 'None' slope raster).

I tried algorithm out in my PC and it works perfectly with absolute paths.

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()

processing.runalg("saga:slopeaspectcurvature",
                   layer,                                                                  #ELEVATION <ParameterRaster>
                   6,                                                                       #METHOD <ParameterSelection>
                   1,                                                                       #UNIT_SLOPE <ParameterSelection>
                   1,                                                                       #UNIT_ASPECT <ParameterSelection>
                   "C:/Users/Usuario/pyqgis_data/slope.tif",                               #SLOPE <OutputRaster>
                   "C:/Users/Usuario/pyqgis_data/aspect.tif",                             #ASPECT <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_GENE <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_PLAN <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_PROF <OutputRaster>  None,                                                                 #C_TANG <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_LONG <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_CROS <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_MINI <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_MAXI <OutputRaster>
                    None,                                                                 #C_TOTA <OutputRaster>
                    None)                                                                 #C_ROTO <OutputRaster>
```

At next image it can be observed aspect raster loaded at QGIS:

[image]